# Aliens have crashed on Earth. Please help them!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Year is 2050. Aliens have been discovered and is now acknowledged as a friendly species towards humans. They now comes for regular visits on Earth and has a friendly relation towards humans. One day, a UFO was on a regular patrol toward Venus but suddenly it suffered a failure and crashed on Earth. Inside there are 7 aliens. All look tensed and worried but they knew the humans would help them. So, they started discussing who is going to bring the repairing kit from the humans. Following is the conversation:

> A1: I am skinny. I am so skinny that I might blow away as soon as I
> step outside. Somebody, please go. I can't.
>
> A2: I can't even sustain on Earth's environment. There is no way I am going.
>
> A3: Hey, chill. I have been here once. I came to know that I am quite
> famous here. I should go.
>
> A4(To A3): Look, I understand your sentiment but I should be the one
> to go. I am the one who is most sustainable to Earth's environment. Humans like me. I am going.
>
> A5: What about me?! I am quite bright and cheerful. I am also quite helpful to them. I should go.
>
> A6: My body release toxic fumes and rays. Uhh, I don't know, I
> might even kill someone. I am not going
>
> A7: Ehhh, just go, anyone go, enough of this argument. I am fat and obese. I can't listen to your arguments. I am staying inside the chamber. Please go, we are getting late.

**Main question:** What are the names of the aliens?

**Side question:** Who should be the one to go?(Only one can go)

---

Hint #1:

> They should be panicking by now but they are calm, like really calm. Why are they so calm? How are they so calm?

Hint #2:

> Something related to chemistry (klabuster_'s answer is partially correct)

Comment: Rot 13 ideas: Zl thrff vf gung gur nyvraf ercerfrag fbzr fbeg bs curabzraba, yvxryl nfgebabzvpny ("rkgengreerfgevny") va angher. Jung fbegf bs guvatf rzvg gbkvp enlf naq shzrf? Jung vf fxvaal? Jung vf snzbhf?

Comment: @Feryll rot13(Vg pna or sbhaq va rkgengreerfgevny cynprf ohg vf pregnvayl abg n curabzraba)

Answer (score 5):

I think they are from A1 to A7

> A1=Helium A2=Neon A3=Krypton A4=Argon A5=Xenon A6=Radon and A7=Oganesson

I'm not sure with every clue, but I still think it fits.

A1: I am skinny. I am so skinny that I might blow away as soon as I step outside. Somebody, please go. I can't.

> Helium: the lightest of noble gas

A2: I can't even sustain on Earth's environment. There is no way I am going.

> Neon: It's quite rare on earth since it, highly volatile and forms no compounds to fix it to solids, escapes the planet

A3: Hey, chill. I have been here once. I came to know that I am quite famous here. I should go

> Krypton: Superman came from Krypton and is quite famous?

A4(To A3): Look, I understand your sentiment but I should be the one to go. I am the one who is most sustainable to Earth's environment. Humans like me. I am going.

> Argon, the third-most abundant gas in the Earth's atmosphere

A5: What about me?! I am quite bright and cheerful. I am also quite helpful to them. I should go.

> Xenon: lamps (bright), many other useful applications (general anesthetic[cheerful?], lasers..)

A6: My body release toxic fumes and rays. Uhh, I don't know, I might even kill someone. I am not going

> Radon: radioactive

A7: Ehhh, just go, anyone go, enough of this argument. I am fat and obese. I can't listen to your arguments. I am staying inside the chamber. Please go, we are getting late.

> Oganesson: heavy (highest atomic number and highest atomic mass), synthetic chemical element (->chamber)

Side question: Who should be the one to go?(Only one can go)

> ???

Hint #1:

> Noble gases are typically highly unreactive

Comment: rot13(Lbh ner evtug nobhg gur anzrf bs gur nyvraf. Ohg fbzr bs gur anzrf ner abg va beqre/zngpuvat jvgu gur uvagf/pbairefngvba. Gel bapr ntnva)

Comment: rot13(V thrff Uryvhz Kraba Enqba naq Btnarffba ner pbeerpg?)

Comment: rot13(gjb bs gurz ner pbeerpg)

Comment: also rot13(gb uryc lbh pynevsl, V unir nqqrq na rkgen jbeq gb n-gjb juvpu fubhyq uryc)

Comment: ro13(V punatrq N-guerr jvgu N-sbhe, ohg fgvyy ab vqrb sbe gur arj N2 pyhr)

Comment: rot13(Lbh ner nyzbfg gurer. Sbhe bs gurz ner pbeerpg)

Comment: This starts to feel like mastermind ;) But everything I would add at the moment would be wild guesssing

Answer (score 2):

One possibility could just be to take everything literally.

For example, "I am skinny" literally means that A1 is named "skinny". One suspicious part that supports this idea is where it says "A4**(To A3)**: Look, I understand...". One reason to point out who A4 is addressing is because he/she is saying A3's name. On the other hand, "A3: Hey, chill" doesn't need to specify a person since there is a "Hey" in front.

This is definitely a stretch since the names of A1 and A2 ("skinny" and "chill") are both lowercase while the name of A3 ("Look") is uppercase.

I don't know what the names of the other four aliens could be using this logic, but one possibility is that they have exceptionally confusing names like "I", "me", "someone", "somebody", "anyone". Also, I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence that A4 says "I am **the one** who is..." while the side question says "Who should be **the one** to go?(Only **one** can go). So if aliens can have multiple words as a name, like "the one", some of the "I am..."s later on could make sense. Also, A6 and A7 say "Uhh" and "Ehhh", but it doesn't specify that they are addressing someone.

Sorry this was a long and confusing explanation of a sketchy solution.

Comment: Good attempt. Unfortunately, not the answer.